# Compare the value in the first column BUT not in the second column in SQL

Tags: sql

I have one database with 2 column. I would like to get the value appear in COl 1 BUT not in COl2(in this data is 3,4,5). I run my SQL code, but the result is null. What is the reason and what is the true answer(WITHOUT USING 'JOIN')

Data:

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| 1    | null |
| 2    | 1    |
| 3    | 2    |
| 4    | 2    |
| 5    | 2    |
+------+------+
```

My code:

```
SELECT t.Col1
  FROM data AS t
 WHERE t.Col1 NOT IN (SELECT t1.Col2 FROM data AS t1)
```

Comment: So is this Posgres or MySQL???

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXISTS in MySQL or Pstgres

```
CREATE TABLE data
    (`Col1` int, `Col2` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO data
    (`Col1`, `Col2`)
VALUES
    (1, NULL),
    (2, '1'),
    (3, '2'),
    (4, '2'),
    (5, '2')
;
```

```
SELECT t.Col1
  FROM data AS t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM data AS t1 WHERE col2 = t.Col1)
```

| Col1 |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n7ToDcCJ)